# check unicode char in all of string positions

Tags: java, android

i'm writing simple sms manager and i want to set counter for all typed characters,for have this ability i must be check char in all string position when user is typing, for example after start to type char by user i'm checking char unicode, if user type in middle string type as char i must be can check it, for more example i have one variable as

```
int counter = 160;
```

if user typed english char, counter value is 160, if user type unicode counter must be 70. my problem is check char in all typed string position user can be type start of string or end of that or middle of string, my simple code has error :

```
02-28 15:50:36.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3022): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

how to resolve this code:

```
String text = uiFiller.edt_sms_body.getText().toString();
if (text.length() <= 0)
    return;

int position = 0;
if (start != 0)
    position = start;

char c = text.substring(position).charAt(0);

String lang = UC.DetectLanguageInEditText(c) ? "fa" : "en";

/* check lang */
```

Comment: what happens if start is grater or equal than text.length()?

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks sir, i forget that